# Why does Programmatic Node Unpublish not Work?

Tags: nodes, 9

We recently upgraded to Drupal 9.3.0 using a Composer file layout.  The resulting website is working correctly and is now running in the publish domain.  We have a set of utilities that we run as Drush scripts.  One of these unpublishes content that we do not want google and other search engines to find -- yet.

I moved into the directory that contains composer.json -- one level above the webroot.  I ran `composer require drush/drush` which added `"drush/drush": "^11.0",` to composer.json and updated the vendor directory accordingly.  I then created a small php script to unpublish a node -- named x.php:

```
<?php
  
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

print "Top\n";
  $node = Node::load('1881');
  $node->setPublished(FALSE);
  $node->save();
print "Bot\n";
```

I ran `vendor/drush/drush/drush scr x.php`. The script runs without error and prints "Top" and "Bot" as expected. However, running this commend Did Not unpublish nid = 1881.  I ran the command again with the `-d` switch which gave me lots of output -- but no error messages to work with.  I checked the error_log for the website -- nothing.  I added a `var_dump($node);` after the `$node = Node::load('1881');` and can see the node is being loaded.

I need to unpublish over 700 nodes and do not want to do this manually. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Not knowing your setup but probably better to implement a post update hook or a deploy hook with a proper batch process. Loading and resaving 700 nodes can be risky to run out of memory.

Comment: Where do you get the node IDs from? You just have a list of them or you get them from a query?

Comment: The actual script is recursive that uses node ids that are stored in the nodes.  For example, all the leaf nodes of a landing page store the node id of the landing page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Drupal 9 `setPublished(FALSE)` doesn't work anymore, the boolean argument is ignored. This was split into two methods:

```
// publish entitiy
$entity->setPublished();

// unpublish entity
$entity->setUnpublished();
```

The change record: https://www.drupal.org/node/2830201

See the linked issue:

**API changes**

- New EntityPublishedInterface added and implemented by Node and Comment
- The parameter for setPublished() is now optional. No parameter will just set the entity as published, but the old TRUE or FALSE parameters will work as they always have for backwards compatibility. This parameter will be removed in 9.0.0.